# UITableViewCell prevent deletion

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am looking for a way of preventing the deleting of one of my cells. (No delete button should appear next to the cell when the table view is in editing mode.)

How can this be made possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Implement editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath and return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone for that row:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == sss && indexPath.row == rrr)
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    else
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought it would be...thanks very much for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

The accepted response works but is not the correct way to do it. There are two methods available: `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` and `canEditRowAtIndexPath`

**editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath**: Use when there are multiple different editing styles in the table

**canEditRowAtIndexPath**: Use when some rows should edit and some should not.

Therefore the correct way to implement your table delegate is:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == sss && indexPath.row == rrr)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```